# Append websocket data to state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to create a timeseries plot that displays data collected from a websocket.

However, when I get new values, they are overwriting the previous one stored in the state.

`const [chartData, setChartData] = React.useState(null)`

My websocket uses setChartData() but this causes me to lose the previous value.

I have a socket that takes setChartData as an argument and on receiving a message calls setChartData(decodedData)

```
const Socket = ({url, protocol, dataFunction}) => {
    const ws = new Websocket(url);
    ws.onmessage = function onMessage(msg) {
        if (protocol === JSON) {
        const decoded = JSON.parse(msg.data)
        dataFunction(decoded)
        }
    }
}
```

How do I go about adding these new values to a state array, rather than just the most recent value?

Comment: How are you adding them to state?  Please include relevant code in the question.

Comment: @David I have added some extra context of how my code works

Comment: You didn't show where you are using `setChartData` which I guess is in `dataFunction`

Answer (score 0):

To *append* your new data to your already populated state array (instead of just replacing it), you can pass an [*updater function*](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#updating-state-based-on-the-previous-state) to the state setter to re-use the previous state content, and above all make sure to create [*a new array*](https://react.dev/learn/updating-arrays-in-state) from your combined data:

> **you should treat arrays in React state as read-only.**
>
> [...]
>
> every time you want to update an array, you’ll want to pass a new array to your state setting function.

In your case:

```
// Actually a state setter (received as a prop in your case)
dataFunction(
  // Updater function form, receives the previous/pending state as argument
  (previousState) => [
    // Return a NEW array, e.g. using spread syntax
    ...previousState,
    ...decoded // Assuming it is an array
  ]
)
```